# How much disk space do the "command line developer tools" take up?

Tags: macos, command-line, install, git

When I run `git --version` in the Terminal, I get prompted to install the "command line developer tools":

[image: Prompt for installing command line developer tools]

What exactly do I get from these "command line developer tools", and how much disk space will the installation use up? I don't want to drag along a whole bunch of useless programs just because I want to use a single command.

(Assume that I do not want to use Homebrew, for whatever reason. The question is asking about the disk space used up by an installation of Apple's "command line developer tools").

Comment: As you now may have deduced from comments I deleted , `git`, like `java`, are stub binaries. Apple doesn’t ship `git` proper with the OS. The stub invokes an installer that will download via a network call a signed copy of the entire framework.  Installer is suitable for your CPU type and patched as of when you install it as opposed to when Apple cut the GM seed of macOS.  This is how Apple rolls now - same as with legal requirements [in Russia where apps install you](https://daringfireball.net/2021/04/in_russia_iphone_apps_install_you).

Comment: Given the OPs actual problem should we edit the question to make that clearer - but then again there is a good answer to the headline question

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use homebrew? It would probably be the cleanest alternative.

Comment: @EricDuminil I was wondering whether or not there are built-in methods to install only Git on MacOS. I don't want to install yet another piece of software (Homebrew) if it can be avoided.

Comment: @Flux: Okay. But since you want to install yet another piece of software (git), you'll have to install *something*. And it's easy to remove homebrew if you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The installer says it requires 2.72 Gb of space. It installs a variety of Unix tools for compiling software, and other advanced usage (such as `git`) on the command line, including 'many other useful commands that are usually found in default linux installations' ([osxdaily.com](https://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/)). It also includes the SDK frameworks and header files for macOS APIs. And `python3`.

Separating out what it is exactly that you need and what you don't is not really feasible, and may cause errors. Presumably, you're doing some kind of scripting/programming, for which other tools in the CLDT might be useful.

Comment: 2.72 GB?! What a waste of disk space! I am not doing any kind of programming. I only need Git to place some txt files into version-control.

Comment: Then as suggested by mmmmmm, install git separately, or use some other version control method.

Comment: @Flux your reaction is correct here. By decoupling this framework from the core OS, Apple doesn’t have to patch everyone’s git - only the people that chose to install it as a feature. Millions of people no longer have git taking space on their computers, but you have to go get it one way or another.

Comment: @bmike: Still, 2.72GB is completely ridiculous, considering that the underlying system already has many command line tools. Why is it so large?

Comment: @EricDuminil It's not just a few command line tools: it's libraries, compilers, and everything needed to build stuff on the CLI. Considering Xcode itself is near 30 Gb, getting it down to under one tenth is pretty impressive.

Comment: @benwiggy: So it's basically the equivalent of `build-essentials` on Ubuntu. Considering how bloated those "command line dev tools" seem to be, I find it impressive that Xcode can still be 10 times as bloated. Software providers get lazier and lazier simply because storage is getting cheaper. It's not a good trend.

Comment: @benwiggy Where can I find the official documentation about "command line developer tools", and the system requirements for installing and running them? (I am generally unfamiliar with Apple products).

Comment: @EricDuminil Given the size of the Ubunto tools, then clearly No. But if storage is cheap, then why not take advantage of it, if it brings functionality? I don't pretend to know whether Apple could produce something smaller without loss of function, or without having to manage several separate tool sets. It is what it is.

Comment: @Flux LOL, mine says I need 26GB of free space to install, I'm just trying to install ffmpeg,  wtf, my whole drive is only 128GB and monterey takes up like half of it.  fml

Answer (score 7):

As [@benwiggy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418056/237) says you cannot split up the command line tools.

However if the issue is just that you want git then there are other ways

- Install command line git binary and associated tools from the [Git downloads web page](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
- Install a git GUI tool that includes its own copy of git efor example [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). Other Git GUI clients are listed on the  [Git website](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the screenshot of the traffic captured by a Unify Dream Machine Pro:

[image]

The SSL/TLS connection which downloaded 189 MB was the Visual Studio Code download which instructed me to install the developer tools. So for version 2395 we have 2.84 GB of data.

When I log into the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line) I can see downloads which are not more than 700 MB in size like Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.4. The numbers don't add up here.

```bash
bt@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro ~ % git --version
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

bt@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro ~ % git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

bt@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro ~ % xcode-select --print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

bt@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro ~ % xcode-select --version   
xcode-select version 2395.

bt@Benjamins-MacBook-Pro ~ %  du -hs /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
2.1G    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

The device is an M1 powered MBP late 2021 with macOS 12.4.

Looking further, now "Software Update" from the control panel tells me that there are updates available  for Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.2, 13.3 and 13.4. Each around 590 to 740 MB. So you download old software to then download newer software and 3 different releases. This will make sense at some point in my Mac journey, but for the start I only wanted git-cli which should be no more than 50 MB, at least that would be [close](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/git) to what Ubuntu does including direct dependencies.

Comment: I ran `xcode-select --install` and it said 25GB space required, 147 hours to download. Outrageous absurdity. I don't know what funky business is going on with the default downloader. Eventually I went to dev portal to manually download `Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.4.dmg` - 723MB, 2min.

Comment: @hackape do you have a link for this?

Comment: @Shawn find that link in OP’s post.

Comment: Size of download != size on disk, git != CLT (which includes way more than git) and the full Xcode install is way bigger than the CLT alone. Also, if Software Update offers 13.2, 13.3 and 13.4, you don't need to download the outdated versions but can go for 13.4 straigt.

Answer (score 0):

- https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ on 2024-03-31 listed:

  - [Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_15.3.dmg](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_15.3/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_15.3.dmg) which according to [Suspicious Package.app](https://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) will require a **disk space of 4.02 GB in total**, spread among these directories:
- 4.02 GB in total in `/Library/Developers/CommandLineTools/`

  - 427  MB for `Library/`
  - 1.14 GB for `SDKs/`

    - 522  MB for `MacOSX13.3`
    - 617  MB for `MacOSX14.4`
  - 2.45 GB for `usr/`